# Firebase function in vue project won't deploy to google cloud

Tags: firebase, vue.js, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I have a vue project. It has a firebase function. I was able to deploy the function to google cloud once. But trying to deploy it later, I find I'm unable to.

Here is the console output from Visual Studio Code:

> PS C:\udemy\vue-firebase\geo-ninjas> firebase deploy --only functions
>
> === Deploying to 'g-s-geo-ninjas'...
>
> i  deploying functions
>   Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
>
> functions@ lint C:\udemy\vue-firebase\geo-ninjas\functions
>   eslint .
>
> - functions: Finished running predeploy script.
>     i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
> - functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
>     i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
>     i  functions: packaged functions (38.34 KB) for uploading
> - functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
>     i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function checkAlias(us-central1)...
>     !  functions[checkAlias(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
>     Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try > deploying again after a few minutes.
>
> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
>           checkAlias
>
> To try redeploying those functions, run:
>       firebase deploy --only functions:checkAlias
>
> To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
>       firebase deploy --except functions
>
> Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
>
> PS C:\udemy\vue-firebase\geo-ninjas>

When I look at the logs in the firebase console, I see this:

> {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":13,"message":"INTERNAL"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"junk.mail291276@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"requestAttributes":{},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/g-s-geo-ninjas/locations/us-central1/functions/checkAlias"}

I widdled down my checkAlias function to the bare minimum that would function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.checkAlias = functions.https.onCall(data => {});
```

...and this still won't deploy.

I've ran eslint and this has no lint errors. When I run this locally, it works.

Why would I be getting these errors when trying to deploy my firebase function?

Comment: Maybe "functions" is a reserved word somewhere. Try changing to `const fbFunctions = ...`

Comment: Thanks Andrew but unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @GibranShah Hi, do you still have the problem?